# Dismiss Alert in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I was wondering if it is possible to dismiss an `Alert` in React-Native from  the main application itself, programmatically?

As an example, my application shows an Alert. When the user stays on that screen for a while and the session of the app expires, the user gets redirected to the login screen but the Alert stays open and I'd like to close it while this happen.

Is there a way to do something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You have to use a custom alert box or a modal and than close it if needed.