# React Native - Programmatically dismiss Alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, alert

I have a TextInput [AlertIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert) in React Native:

```
 AlertIOS.prompt(
  'Enter password',
  'Enter your password to claim your $1.5B in lottery winnings',
  [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {
      text: 'OK',
      onPress: (password) => password.trim() != "" ? Dismiss ALERT : KEEP ALERT,
    },
  ],
  'secure-text',
);
```

Is there a way to only programmatically dismiss the alert? I.e. when clicking on a non-cancel option, I want to dismiss the alert only if a condition holds.

Would this be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismiss Alert in React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676023/dismiss-alert-in-react-native)

Answer (score -2):

if you want to dismiss the alert when you tap on `Cancel` button, you could make an empty function like this `onPress: () => {}` instead of `console.log()`.
If you want to dismiss the alert if a condition holds, you could try this:

```
onPress: (password) => password.trim() !== "" ? this.doSomething() : this.doAnotherStuff();
```

or

```
onPress: (password) => password.trim() !== "" ? this.doSomething() : () => {};
```